# Sleep Apps and Shared Beds

Tags: applications, sleep

I've seen on the marketplace now several alarm clock applications that claim to analyze your motion patterns in your sleep, so as to determine the ideal time to wake you up such that you feel refreshed.  I am intrigued by this possibility;  however, I do not sleep alone.  Does anyone know if these apps work well, or even at all, if there are multiple individuals in the bed, each presumably moving on their own sleep cycle?

Comment: Can you post a link to the app? It sounds really interesting.

Comment: There are several apps of this category;  here's one example https://market.android.com/details?id=com.kyotoap.android.sleepcyclealarmlite&feature=search_result

Comment: https://market.android.com/search?q=Sleep+Cycle&so=1&c=apps

Comment: Yeah found some now.. too tired to be able to search ;)

Answer (score 1):

No, it would probably not work if you don't sleep alone unless the one you sleep with don't move at all in their sleep.

Comment: I'd say it depends on the sleeping arrangements. Tempurpedic, for instance, markets heavily on the idea that your partner can jump up and down on the bed and it won't disturb you.

Comment: Yeah, but that would ruin the idea at the same time. If it won't disturb me that my BF is jumping in the bed, next to me, how is the app going to sense when you move in your sleep?

Comment: I think, it is worth trying to use this alarm with some kind of arm strap for your smartphone. These straps are ofter used with MP3 flash players. The divice's accelerometer will register *your* arm movement. But of cource, it wouldn't be able to determine if you moved your arm yourself or someone pushed it.

Answer (score 1):

In short. It doesn't work.

The movements you have when you sleep indicates "muscle paralyzation", which is one of the factors that indicates your REM sleep cycle. However, this is one of the not-so-accurate ones. If you want real accuracy, you will need those that measure ECG with a headband (Zeo, for example).

In addition, most apps in the market does not give an accurate reading of your movements due to interference and sensor sensitivities.